# How to unbox vector with 2 values

Tags: haskell, statistics, box, haskell-vector

I am trying to do wilcoxonMatchedPairTest as given [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.15.0.0/docs/Statistics-Test-WilcoxonT.html):

```
import Data.Vector as V
import Statistics.Test.WilcoxonT

sampleA = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4]
sampleB = [2.0,4.0,5.0,5.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6]

main = do
    putStrLn "\nResult of wilcoxonMatchedPairTest: "
    print (wilcoxonMatchedPairTest AGreater (Prelude.zip sampleA sampleB))
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
rnwilcox.hs:10:50: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector
                                      (a0, a0)’
                  with actual type ‘[(Double, Double)]’
    • In the second argument of ‘wilcoxonMatchedPairTest’, namely
        ‘(Prelude.zip sampleA sampleB)’
      In the first argument of ‘print’, namely
        ‘(wilcoxonMatchedPairTest AGreater (Prelude.zip sampleA sampleB))’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        print
          (wilcoxonMatchedPairTest AGreater (Prelude.zip sampleA sampleB))
```

Apparently, I need to unbox the vector here. I tried using `#` as follows:

```
(# Prelude.zip sampleA sampleB #)
```

But it does not work. Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the list of 2-tuples to a `Vector` with [**`fromList :: Unbox a => [a] -> Vector a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#v:fromList) here from the `Data.Vector.Unboxed` package to create such a vector:

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU
import Statistics.Test.WilcoxonT

main = do
    putStrLn "\nResult of wilcoxonMatchedPairTest: "
    print (wilcoxonMatchedPairTest AGreater (VU.fromList (Prelude.zip sampleA sampleB)))
```

or if you have two `Vector`s, you can use [**`zip :: (Unbox a, Unbox b) => Vector a -> Vector b -> Vector (a, b)`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#v:zip) to zip two `Vector`s to a `Vector` of items:

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU
import Statistics.Test.WilcoxonT

sampleA = VU.fromList [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4]
sampleB = VU.fromList [2.0,4.0,5.0,5.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6]

main = do
    putStrLn "\nResult of wilcoxonMatchedPairTest: "
    print (wilcoxonMatchedPairTest AGreater (VU.zip sampleA sampleB))
```

For the given sample data, this gives us:

```
Prelude VU Statistics.Test.WilcoxonT> main

Result of wilcoxonMatchedPairTest: 
Test {testSignificance = mkPValue 1.0, testStatistics = 36.0, testDistribution = ()}
```